# Converting all database strings to uppercase

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need an SQL script that will go through all nvarchar columns on all tables in my database, and convert them to UPPER().  Any idea how to go about automating this without having to manually specify the columns to work on?

Comment: Why do you have such a weird requirement? If you want to display words uppercase you should do that where you display them and not in the database. Why isn't this sufficient: `SELECT UPPER(Col)AS UpperCol FROm Table`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have this weird requirement, as your DB has a case sensitive collation or something. The solution linked in the comment to your question works fine, but does not handle only `nvarchar` columns on `user defined` tables.

If this is a one time requirement, this solution should work, but is not the most efficient approach:

```
DECLARE @updates TABLE
(
    tablename  sysname,
    columnname sysname 
)
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max);
INSERT INTO @updates (tablename,columnname) 
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(c.OBJECT_ID) TableName, c.name ColumnName
FROM sys.columns AS c
JOIN sys.types AS t ON c.user_type_id=t.user_type_id
JOIN sys.tables AS tb ON c.object_id = tb.object_id AND tb.type = 'U'
WHERE t.name = 'nvarchar' --you can change text to other datatypes
ORDER BY c.OBJECT_ID;

DECLARE @tablename sysname,@columnname sysname
DECLARE caseupdate CURSOR 
FOR
Select tablename,columnname FROM @updates 
OPEN caseupdate
FETCH NEXT FROM caseupdate INTO @tablename,@columnname
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SET @SQL = 'UPDATE '+@tablename+' SET '+@columnname+' =UPPER('+@columnname+')'
    EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL
    SET @SQL=''
    FETCH NEXT FROM caseupdate INTO @tablename,@columnname
END
CLOSE caseupdate 
DEALLOCATE caseupdate
```

Comment: The solution I posted in the link would be extemely simple to restrict to `nvarchar` only (just add a where clause) and far better than using cursors.

Comment: True about adding `WHERE` clause. Also can be modified to include only `User` tables. Would the resulting SQL statement update multiple tables / columns at a time, or will it run one statement at a time?

Comment: It will create a SQL command for each field in each table.

Comment: That was not the question. Will it execute all the commands simultaneously was the question.

Comment: That depends on how you interpret simultaneously. It will build a string of multiple commands and call the execute method once.  However each of the `UPDATE` commands will be executed by the server one after the other.

Comment: So, how is it more effective than a cursor?